# Enable/Disable Required field validator from cs page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I have two TextBox and two Buttons in my page.

One is hidden and the other one is displayed.

When I click the `Button1`, it will save data of the two `TextBox` and will validate each TextBox by the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Then when I click `Button2`, it will just hide itself (`Button2`) and will show the hidden `TextBox`.

Both `TextBox` has `RequiredFieldValidator` validating against `Button1`'s Event click.

Now my issue is when I simply enter text to the 1st TextBox and click save, the button click is validating the required field for hidden field. I just want to validate the 2 textbox when it is showing.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: ControlToValidate property is there to which control validate or Post your code we will help u.

Comment: Can you provide some of your codes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well you can simple use the `Enabled="false"` property of `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Your `markup` would look something like this based on your Question.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv1" ControlToValidate="tb1" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="gvSave">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb2" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv2" ControlToValidate="tb2" ErrorMessage="*" Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="gvSave">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Save" onclick="btn1_Click" ValidationGroup="gvSave"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn2" Text="Show" onclick="btn2_Click" />
```

And your `codebehind` like this:

```
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb2.Visible = true;
    rfv2.Enabled = true; // Enables the second requiredfieldvalidator
}

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // your Saving code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hinting `ValidationGroup` to me.

Comment: Helped me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

use the `ValidationGroup="group"` property to `button` and assign validation group to text on which you want to validate.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `CausesValidation="false"` for the secondary button, this is less verbose and potentially confusing when validation groups are A) excessive for a single field and B) you have to maintain validation groups when adding further controls (do we put it on the button, the validator, the field *and* the validation summary? It's not a lot the remember the standard, but less practical when editing.

Answer (score 1):

This is Aspx :

```
                 <td align="right">
                            Cut Type :
                        </td>
                        <td class="required">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbCutType" runat="server" MaxHeight="200px" Width="200px"
                                Filter="Contains" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" EmptyMessage="Select Cut Type" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbCutType_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="true">
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvCutType" Display="None" ControlToValidate="cmbCutType" InitialValue=""
                                ValidationGroup="Save" ErrorMessage="Cut Type is Mandatory"
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceCutType" TargetControlID="rfvCutType"
                                runat="server">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        </td>
```

This is code behind :

```
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rfvCutType.IsValid = false;
}
```

try this.......

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you use backend validation then check this out, it worked for me.

```
Requiredfieldvalidator.Enabled = False
```

Requiredfieldvalidator is an ID.

The project I am working has all the fields visible but based on certain conditions, validation has to be disabled.