# Disable RequiredFieldValidator on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

Im trying to disable RequiredFieldValidator on a button click but I cant seem to figure out how. I've also tried .Enabled property with no luck. This is what I have but its not working. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

```
protected void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RequiredFieldValidator3.IsValid = false;
    RequiredFieldValidator4.IsValid = false;
    {
        lblCreateAccount.Text = user.CreateAccount();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use property "Enabled"

Comment: I used that as well, but no luck @T.S.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically enable or disable RequiredFieldValidator based on value of DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554840/dynamically-enable-or-disable-requiredfieldvalidator-based-on-value-of-dropdownl)

Comment: Check the answer above and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827578/enable-disable-required-field-validator-from-cs-page

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking in both of those. Problem is that i still need to leave a few validators enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the control's **CausesValidation** property to false. it will disable validation for a specific control. [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, however I still have a few textboxes validation that I would like to keep enabled. If i can't figure this out I will use your suggestion

Comment: Check **ValidatorEnable** function from here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)

You can disable like
function Disable(){           ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator1'), false);
}

and call that function in buttons 'onclientclick' event, and you need to handle control rendering after postback