# C# Enable and Disable Validators on Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am doing a customer registration form which allows new customers to fill in. I've put requirefieldvalidator every field and comparevalidator for comparingt the password and confirmpassword. I have submit button and back button. The problem i encountered is no matter what button i clicked, submit button or back button, if i don't fill in any of the requirement i will not proceed. This is fine to the submit button as it needs to check whether every detail is filled in, but for back button, i want to allow customers to go back to previous page by clicking this button which validators are not needed.

Is there any way to control the validators?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827578/enable-disable-required-field-validator-from-cs-page Hi, check this link. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ValidationGroup in all validation with same group name  and give same group name for button also

**Exapmle**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv1" ControlToValidate="tb1" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="gvSave">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb2" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv2" ControlToValidate="tb2" ErrorMessage="*" Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="gvSave">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Save" onclick="btn1_Click" ValidationGroup="gvSave"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn2" Text="Show" onclick="btn2_Click" />
```

*Here*

when you click btn1 it check for validation and

for button btn2 will not check for validation